# what caused IOException and Broken pipe

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My AVD is of API 15, I don't know why but the following message keeps coming up whenever I run an application on emulator. It doesn't seem to have caused any trouble except for the error message in console.

```
[2012-06-17 00:03:26 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:122)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:352)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 32):

If someone uses both eclipse and android studio together, then this error will be thrown by eclipse. So even if you select the device through DDMS, its gonna throw this error.

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but still relevant and I didn't see any other answer with this information:

For me it happened when another Eclipse was running at the same time, with DDMS competing over the same socket as the eclipse trying to connect to the Android device.

Solution was to close the other Eclipse. Hope it helps someone.

**Update**: Probably a better solution is to edit the DDMS port of the other eclipse to something you don't use. So it's out of the race.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I had this problem while running Eclipse on the Guest Account and on my User account. Once I turned off Eclipse on my Guest Account, the problem was solved.

Comment: In my case it was Android Studio that was running in parallel to Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me when I had both `monitor` and Eclipse ADT open. Try closing all Android related stuff and then do a `adb kill-server && sleep 5 && adb devices` and then start your tool (Eclipse/Ant/AS) again.

Comment: Also, close any other Android Studio instances open from which you had launched an app.

Comment: I found that just using `adb kill-server` addressed the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

'Broken pipe' means you have written data to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. Solution: don't. It is essentially an application protocol error.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that the client (Eclipse) communicate with the Server (your Emulator) by Pipe protocol (This protocol is well-know to communicate 2 process on the same machine).

The communication channel can be broken sometimes. (There are possible 100+ reason for that)

To solve this issue: restart the emulator (AVD). Maybe you will have to wait a moment (~1min??) so Eclipse can restore the Pipe channel and your Log Cat will return. Otherwise, restart both Eclipse & the emulator to get rid of this error.

Comment: I restarted the emulator but still had this problem.  I was able to get a good pipe by going to the AVD manager, deleting the AVD and creating a new one.  Don't know why, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: if the AVD is broken, you can try to open AVD Manager > Start.. > check on "Wipe user data" to reset your AVD

Comment: Bad guess. The exception makes it quite clear that he is using a socket, not a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason I've had for a "broken pipe" is that one machine (of a pair communicating via socket) has shut down its end of the socket before communication was complete. About half of those were because the program communicating on that socket had terminated.

If the program sending bytes sends them out and immediately shuts down the socket or terminates itself, it is possible for the socket to cease functioning before the bytes have been transmitted and read.

Try putting pauses anywhere you are shutting down the socket and before you allow the program to terminate to see if that helps.

FYI: "pipe" and "socket" are terms that get used interchangeably sometimes.

Comment: If a program sends data and then closes the socket, the socket keeps sending the data until it has all been acknowledged or a failure occurs. Adding pauses to network programs only exhibits misunderstanding of the underlying problem. It doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this happening frequently (every 5 mins or so) recently.
The frequency seemed to increase if I had both a physical device and an emulator running.

Stopping the emulator and only using the physical device for debugging stopped it from happening as often - now I only see it once or twice a day.

To resolve it when it happens, you don't need to close down the emulator or reboot the device - turning USB Debugging Mode off and back on should make it show up again under adb.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. Whenever I wanted to debug android mobile application with Chrome's debug tool I got disconnected every 5 mintutes.

I found out that the cause of this is indeed other process using connection to mobile phone that is running behind in OS that breaks the communication between mobile phone and OS.

I use Macbook Pro and I was running IntelliJ IDEA debugger + Android File Transfer (didn't knew this was running behind) and Chrome's debugger tool. When I closed Android File Transfer process with "Activity Monitor" tool everything was working well, no more disconnection between mobile phone and OS. My suggestion is to check always if you are running other Android process.

Answer (score 0):

A "Broken pipe" exception occurs when a socket connection is closed by the client on the other side. Most of the time this is nothing to worry about.

Comment: So why could the client be closed on the other size?

Comment: The program on the other end closed or the user stopped the request. For example, click on a link in an html page and the browser will close all other pending requests, the server will then encounter these "Broken pipe" exceptions.

Comment: So my doubt is why it happened when I merely ran an application on emulator?

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace my guess would be the emulator dropped the connection with the IDE(?). Maybe because it was not ready or a new version was uploaded instead?

Comment: Why is it nothing to worry about when you've tried to write to a socket that the peer has already closed? Aren't application protocol errors of any concern?

Answer (score 0):

I was using both Android Studio and DDMS. Closing DDMS fixed the problem for me.

Restarting Android Studio had no impact.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one else did not find any solution to this. In eclipses Neon, this happened when i had two DDMS jars in the plugins directory. I had the andmore.ddms.jar and com.android_ddms.jar. Deleting one solves the error, i guess they both compete to connect to the same port.

Answer (score 0):

restarting the android device fixed my problem

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I remove the the .android in my home directory.
That's Ok.