# IOException: Broken pipe when running Android application

Tags: java, android

When trying to run my Android app from Eclipse I get this error in the console:

```
    [2013-03-04 14:19:05 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
    java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:89)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:450)
        at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:605)
        at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:451)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

How do I fix this kind of error?

When I did `adb connect <IP_ADDRESS>` it showed connected to 192.168.0.109:5555

Comment: did you try restarting the Eclipse?

Comment: Restart Emulator or re-plugged data cable of connected device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is usually caused due to the IO pipe between eclipse and your emulator being broken. You don't usually need to worry about this if it isn't causing any problems in your app. Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11065509/1369222).

Answer (score 2):

on win7 and using GenyMotion
I

1.open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager;

2.from a menu select File -> Preferences...;

3.in the opened window switch to Network;

4.on the right hand there are three icons, the lowest's tag is 'Edit host-only network(Space)', click on that;

5.new window opens;

6.check wether your 'IPv4 address' (Adapter tab) is between 'Lower Address Bound' and 'Upper Address Bound' (DHCP Server tab);

7.if it is not, make it to be between;

8.if it is, change the 'IPv4 address' address:
           e.g. if the old one was 192.168.112.104, then change it to 192.168.112.105;

9.click OK-buttons on opened windows;

10.try whether your virtual device works again.

Before that I also close all processes related to Virtual* or Virt*, in TaskManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can only close the emulator that is currently running and then start a new one from the IDE that you are using, e.g. eclipse.. runa as.. Android Application. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

On the device
Pull down the notification bar
Select USB for charging
Select Use USB for File transfers

Then change it back to
Select Use USB for Charging

-- also, switch cables or usb ports sometimes helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the USB Cable. I had a slightly broken USB cable which was charging the phone perfectly but gave this error on running any application.