# java.io.IOException: Broken pipe while running android app in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb

I am getting the following error while running android app in eclipse

```
[2014-03-05 17:39:51 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:122)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:352)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:763)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

**what does this error means?**

Comment: is this full logcat? probably you forgot to close a socket in your app

Comment: It is not in logcat. It is in console(DDMS)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what caused IOException and Broken pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065509/what-caused-ioexception-and-broken-pipe)