# Unable to write to OutputStream [java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]

Tags: java, android, sockets, outputstream, unix-socket

I am trying to send HTTP request to Abstract Unix Socket within an Android Application, using `LocalSocket` but it gives `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe`. Status of `isConnected()` is `true` at the same time and I have also confirmed that the request I send is correct by forwarding the port using `adb` and making the same request using `netcat`.

```
LocalSocket receiver = new LocalSocket();
receiver.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("chrome_devtools_remote", LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.ABSTRACT));
InputStream input = receiver.getInputStream();
StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder().append("GET /json HTTP/1.0")
receiver.getOutputStream().write(request.toString().getBytes());
```

Unable to figure out what's going wrong. Help appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: and of course you are not doing this on main thread?

Comment: Yes, its on a separate thread.

Comment: @Selvin Android (Zygote) won't allow this on main Thread, will throw a Zygote error then, not an ioe

Comment: Are you using Eclipse and Android Studio together?

Comment: These answers might help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19091168/928952 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/22764106/928952

Comment: I amn't using both. Building it using `ant`.